# Laravel 8 - Serialization of 'NumberFormatter' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, queue

Recently, I have been receiving error saying "Serialization of 'NumberFormatter' is not allowed" when processing queued jobs.

Here is the full error log:

```
[2021-11-16 06:38:31] local.ERROR: Serialization of 'NumberFormatter' is not allowed {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Serialization of 'NumberFormatter' is not allowed at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php:162)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(162): serialize()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(127): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createObjectPayload()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(105): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createPayloadArray()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SyncQueue.php(38): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->createPayload()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php(57): Illuminate\\Queue\\SyncQueue->push()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php(133): Illuminate\\Queue\\Queue->pushOn()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(320): Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager->queue()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(243): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->broadcastEvent()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/BroadcastChannel.php(51): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(148): Illuminate\\Notifications\\Channels\\BroadcastChannel->send()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(106): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->sendToNotifiable()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Localizable.php(19): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->Illuminate\\Notifications\\{closure}()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(109): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->withLocale()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/ChannelManager.php(54): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->sendNow()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/SendQueuedNotifications.php(104): Illuminate\\Notifications\\ChannelManager->sendNow()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Notifications\\SendQueuedNotifications->handle()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(128): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(132): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(120): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow()
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(122): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(70): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware()
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(98): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->call()
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(428): Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\Job->fire()
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(378): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process()
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(172): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(117): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon()
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker()
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(299): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(295): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#48 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#49 {main}
"}
```

I checked the Horizon and the failing job is a Notification, here is the code:

```php
class NewOrderNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected Collection $orders;
    protected bool $sendingToTeamMembers;

    public function __construct(Collection $orders, bool $sendingToTeamMembers)
    {
        $this->orders = $orders;
        $this->sendingToTeamMembers = $sendingToTeamMembers;
    }
    
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'database',
            'broadcast',
            'mail',
        ];
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        $order = $this->getPrimaryOrder($this->orders);

        return [
            'category' => 'order_created',
            'item_name' => $order->item_name,
            'total' => $this->orders->count(),
            'purchaser_name' => $order->purchaser_name,
            'payment_amount' => $this->getPaymentAmountSafely($order),
            'order_uuids' => $this->orders->pluck('uuid')->toArray(),
        ];
    }

    public function toTwilio($notifiable)
    {
        $order = $this->getPrimaryOrder($this->orders);

        return (new TwilioSmsMessage())
            ->content(
                __('You have a new order for :amount. Visit :url for more info.', [
                    'amount' => $this->getPaymentAmountSafely($order),
                    // We need to save the chars in SMS by shorten this url
                    'url' => $order->toUrl(true),
                ])
            );
    }
    
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new NewOrderForTeamSubscribedMembersMessage($this->orders))->to($notifiable);
    }
    
    protected function getPaymentAmountSafely(Order $order)
    {
        return optional($order->paymentLog)->total_amount_formatted;
    }

    protected function getPrimaryOrder(Collection $orders): Order
    {
        return $orders->first();
    }
}
```

The weird thing is, I dont see any reference to the `NumberFormatter` class at all.

Also, another weird thing is that some `NewOrderNotification` jobs are processed fine (I checked the Horizon --> Completed Jobs), just some are throwing this exception.

I dont know where to lock as there is not much info in the logs.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

P/S: Im running Laravel 8.70.2 and PHP 8.0

Cheers,

---

#### Update 1:

After spending hours debugging, I find out that removing `broadcast` from the notification `via()` method works like a charm.

But 1 thing I dont understand is: the `database` and `broadcast` call the same `toArray()` method. Why 1 works and not the other?

Comment: `total_amount_formatted` looks like a candidate that might use the number formatter

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos,
That is just a Model getter.

Comment: Ok so this exception would be thrown because you are trying to queue a notification that has an already instiated number formatted contained in it. You need to check if there is any scenario where this happens. I first guessed `total_amount_formatted` because it does sound like something that you'd need a number formatter to generate and if you kept said formatter in the object instance it would result in this error.

Comment: @apokryfos you are right, I commented out the `payment_amount` line in `toArray()` method and it works. However, if I keep that `toArray()` as is, and duplicate that into the `toBroadcast()` method, the `toArray()` still works but not the `toBroadcast()`. So I still dont understand why that only fails when broadcasting?!?